# How to stop jQuery from loading a div if it already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a mock console for my website, but I'm facing a problem that whenever an input value is submitted more than once, jQuery reloads the div since it's marked with a specific id.

I didn't want to clone the div, so I appended a message saying that it already exists. I don't want jQuery to reload it again either so I'm trying to come up with a solution.

### How can I stop jQuery from loading the div if it already exists?

([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yiqeci/edit?html,css,js,output))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    // Check on keydown
    $('.inputs').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            var value = $(this).val();
            var ajax_load = "<p>LOADING<span class=\"blink\">_</span></p>";

            var loadGlossary = "https://unilogue.github.io/commands/glossary.asp";

            var errorLine = $("<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;UNKNOWN COMMAND</span></p><br>");
            var newLine = $('.inputs').clone(true).val('');
            var help = $("<p><span class=\"cmd\"># COMMANDS : [m]ap&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [d]erive [g]lossary<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[?] help [clear]&nbsp; [git]</span></p><br>");

            var glossary = $("<div id=\"div3\"></div>");

            // Tiny jQuery Plugin
            // by Chris Goodchild
            $.fn.exists = function(callback) {
                var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

                if (this.length) {
                    callback.call(this, args);
                }

                return this;
            };

            // Usage
            $(glossary).exists(function() {
                this.append('<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;[g]lossary is already open!</span></p><br>');
            });

            if (value == 'g') { // If input value is div3
                $('.container').append(glossary);
                $("#div3").html(ajax_load).load(loadGlossary);
                $('.container').append("<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p>").append(newLine);
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).removeClass('inputs');
                $('.inputs').replaceWith(newLine);
                $('.inputs:first').focus();
            } else if (value != '') { // If input value is wrong
                $('.container').append(errorLine);
                $('.container').append("<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p>").append(newLine);
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).removeClass('inputs');
                $('.inputs').replaceWith(newLine);
                $('.inputs:first').focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="icon" href="favi.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unilogue.github.io/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div id="prompt">enter the letter 'g' to load the div, notice how it keeps reloading if you enter the letter 'g' again? i don't want that to happen.</div>
    <br>
</header>
<div class="container"><p>&#62;&nbsp;</p><input class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="ENTER COMMAND" /></div>
```

Could I try combining the functions that load the div into one variable, and then create a statement where if the div has `.length()` I could `.detach()` or `.remove()` the variable from the function so that the div doesn't load again?

```
// Tiny jQuery Plugin
// by Chris Goodchild
$.fn.exists = function(callback) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

    if (this.length) {
        callback.call(this, args);
    }

    return this;
};

// Usage
$(glossary).exists(function() {
    this.append('<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;[g]lossary is already open!</span></p><br>');
});

if (value == 'g') { // If input value is div3
    /* combine these --> */  $('.container').append(glossary);
    /* into one var  --> */  $("#div3").html(ajax_load).load(loadGlossary);
    $('.container').append("<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p>").append(newLine);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).removeClass('inputs');
    $('.inputs').replaceWith(newLine);
    $('.inputs:first').focus();
}
```

Combining the last five lines into one variable would also be useful in reducing the length of my code, because I've copied them into each of the `else if` statements of [my script](https://unilogue.github.io/js/index.js). I also think I could possibly make jQuery ignore the entire else if statement and move those last five lines into the plugin by Chris Goodchild, since it already checks to see if the div exists.

**EDIT:** I was able to reduce those equivalent blocks of code into functions, which can now be manipulated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajaxSetup ({
     cache: false
 });



      // Check on keydown
     $('.inputs').keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {

           var value = $(this).val();
           var ajax_load = "<p>LOADING<span class=\"blink\">_</span></p>";


          var loadGlossary = "https://unilogue.github.io/commands/glossary.asp";

           var errorLine = $("<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;UNKNOWN COMMAND</span></p><br>");
           var newLine = $('.inputs').clone(true).val('');

           var glossary = $("<div id=\"div3\"></div>");
              
          $.fn.gCmd = function() {
             $('.container').append(glossary);
             $("#div3").html(ajax_load).load(loadGlossary);
           };

           $.fn.newLine = function() {
            $('.container').append("<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p>").append(newLine);
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).removeClass('inputs');
            $('.inputs').replaceWith(newLine);
            $('.inputs:first').focus();
           };

          // Tiny jQuery Plugin
          // by Chris Goodchild
          $.fn.exists = function(callback) {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

            if (this.length) {
              callback.call(this, args);
            }

            return this;
          };

          // Usage
          $(glossary).exists(function() {
            // maybe the function to prevent .gCmd() could go here?
            this.append('<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;[g]lossary is already open!</span></p><br>');
          });

            if (value == 'g') { // If input value is div3
                $(this).gCmd();
            } else if (value != '') { // If input value is wrong
                $('.container').append(errorLine);
            }
/*appends to all lines */ $(this).newLine();
          }
        });

     


    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="enter a command.">

    <title>unilogue</title>

  <link rel="icon" href="favi.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unilogue.github.io/css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 
  </head>

<body>

<header>
    
    <div id="prompt">enter the letter 'g' to load the div, notice how it keeps reloading if you enter the letter 'g' again? i don't want that to happen.</div>
    <br>
</header>

<div class="container"><p>&#62;&nbsp;</p><input class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="ENTER COMMAND" /></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may need to isolate the issue and create a minimal example.

Comment: i tried to create a minimal example in the snippet. i want this to apply to div1 div2 and div3.

Comment: Is what you are asking is how to take the lines in that last code-block and turn them into a function so you can reuse it rather than having several nearly equivalent blocks of code?

Comment: i just want jquery to stop reloading the divs if they're already present. i believe combining the lines into one variable that can be manipulated might work but i'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i changed `id` to `class` and added a clause which specifies that if the command is re-entered, jQuery must remove the class and append a message.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajaxSetup ({
     cache: false
 });


      // Check on keydown
     $('.inputs').keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {

           var value = $(this).val();
           var ajax_load = "<p>LOADING<span class=\"blink\">_</span></p>";


           var loadGlossary = "https://unilogue.github.io/commands/glossary.asp";

           var errorLine = $("<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;UNKNOWN COMMAND</span></p><br>");
           var newLine = $('.inputs').clone(true).val('');

           var glossary = $("<div class=\"div3\"></div>");

           var gOpen = $('<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;[g]lossary is already open!</span></p><br>');

            $.fn.gCmd = function() {
             $('.container').append(glossary);
             $(".div3").html(ajax_load).load(loadGlossary);
           };

           $.fn.newLine = function() {
            $('.container').append("<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p>").append(newLine);
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).removeClass('inputs');
            $('.inputs').replaceWith(newLine);
            $('.inputs:first').focus();
           };

            if (value == 'g' && !($('.div3').length)) { // If input value is div3
                $(this).gCmd();
            } else if (value == 'g'  && ($('.div3').length)) { // If div3 is present
                $(glossary).removeClass('div3');
                $('.container').append(gOpen);
            } else if (value != '') { // If input value is wrong
                $('.container').append(errorLine);
            }

/*appends2all*/ $(this).newLine();
          }
        });

     $('html').keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 88 && e.ctrlKey) { // value = help
        $('#cmd').show();
        $('#prompt').hide();
    }
         });


    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="enter a command.">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unilogue.github.io/css/style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>

<header>
    <div id="prompt">enter the letter 'g'.</div>
</header>

<div class="container"><p>&#62;&nbsp;</p><input class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="ENTER COMMAND" /></div>

</body>

   
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if an element already exists it's pretty handy to use JQuery and check the length of the element. If the length is 0, it doesn't exist. Something like:

```
if($('#anElement').length)
    return;
else        
    $('<tag>Look! A Thing!</tag>').appendTo('#someOtherElementYouWantThisToAttachTo');
```

I would give more specific examples, but you posted a bunch of code.

EDIT:

Why not try this? Just add a couple clauses to your if/else checks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajaxSetup ({
     cache: false
 });



      // Check on keydown
     $('.inputs').keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {

           var value = $(this).val();
           var ajax_load = "<p>LOADING<span class=\"blink\">_</span></p>";


          var loadGlossary = "https://unilogue.github.io/commands/glossary.asp";

           var errorLine = $("<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;UNKNOWN COMMAND</span></p><br>");
           var newLine = $('.inputs').clone(true).val('');

           var glossary = $("<div id=\"div3\"></div>");

          $.fn.gCmd = function() {
             $('.container').append(glossary);
             $("#div3").html(ajax_load).load(loadGlossary);
           };

           $.fn.newLine = function() {
            $('.container').append("<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p>").append(newLine);
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).removeClass('inputs');
            $('.inputs').replaceWith(newLine);
            $('.inputs:first').focus();
           };

          // Tiny jQuery Plugin
          // by Chris Goodchild
          $.fn.exists = function(callback) {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

            if (this.length) {
              callback.call(this, args);
            }

            return this;
          };

          // Usage
          $(glossary).exists(function() {
            // maybe the function to prevent .gCmd() could go here?
            this.append('<p><span class=\"cmd\">&#62;&nbsp;[g]lossary is already open!</span></p><br>');
          });

            if (value == 'g' && !($('#div3').length)) { // If input value is div3
                $(this).gCmd();
            } else if (value !== '' && $(glossary).length === 0) { // If input value is wrong
                $('.container').append(errorLine);
            }
/*appends to all lines */ $(this).newLine();
          }
        });




    });
```

Comment: the plugin i inserted by Chris Goodchild already checks to see if the div exists, and it returns a message saying it does. i know it's a lot of code but i wanted to provide enough info so anyone could edit my site's code. if i remove the wrong thing the whole thing fails. i'll remove two of the divs so you just have one to work with.

Comment: Edited with update. This will prevent the div from being loaded more than once in a row

Comment: your method worked! but it looks like the errorLine prompt and the Tiny jQuery plugin disappeared. I'll keep working on it,  thanks.